# csv read all row in a column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, read.csv

Good evening
I am trying to read a csv file by pandas but when i display my data frame i find that the whole line is in one column it does not separate between the columns
Here is the result :

[image]

and here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("data/dd.csv",delimiter= ',', engine="python", encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

I was expecting my data frame to be in this form :

[image]

here are my sample :

```
"Report ID, ""Drug Identification Number"", ""Report Type"", ""Brand name"", ""Company Name"", ""Common or Proper name"", Ingredients, Strength(s), ""Packaging size"","" Route of administration"", ""Shortage status"", ""Dosage form(s)"", ""ATC Code"", ""ATC description"", ""Anticipated start date"", ""Actual start date"", ""Estimated end date"", ""Actual end date"", Reason, ""Date Created"", ""Date Updated"", ""Tier 3""     "
"34506,01924303,Shortage,""0.9% SODIUM CHLORIDE INJECTION USP"",""B. BRAUN MEDICAL INC"",""Sodium Chloride"",""SODIUM CHLORIDE"",0.9%,""100mL, 150mL, 250mL, 500mL"",INTRAVENOUS,Resolved,SOLUTION,B05XA,""I.V. SOLUTION ADDITIVES"",2017-12-22,2017-12-22,,2019-01-01,""Disruption of the manufacture of the drug."",2018-01-02,2019-11-06,No      "
"28240,01963937,Shortage,""0.9% SODIUM CHLORIDE IRRIGATION USP"",""B. BRAUN MEDICAL INC"",""Sodium Chloride"",""SODIUM CHLORIDE"",0.9%,""500mL, 1000mL, 2000mL, 4000mL"",IRRIGATION,""Actual shortage"",SOLUTION,B05CB,""IRRIGATING SOLUTIONS"",,2017-11-03,,,""Requirements related to complying with good manufacturing practices."",2017-11-06,2019-04-04,No     "
"43080,00436208,Shortage,""2% LIDOCAINE HYDROCHLORIDE INJECTION USP"",""HOSPIRA HEALTHCARE CORPORATION"",""LIDOCAINE HYDROCHLORIDE LIFESHIELD"",""LIDOCAINE HYDROCHLORIDE"",20MG,""10 x 5mL"",INTRAVENOUS,Resolved,SOLUTION,C01BB,""ANTIARRHYTHMICS, CLASS I AND III"",2018-04-13,,2018-07-13,2018-07-02,""Disruption of the manufacture of the drug."",2018-03-16,2018-07-03,No        "
"51084,00436208,Shortage,""2% LIDOCAINE HYDROCHLORIDE INJECTION USP"",""HOSPIRA HEALTHCARE CORPORATION"",""LIDOCAINE HYDROCHLORIDE ANSYR"",""LIDOCAINE HYDROCHLORIDE"",20MG,""10 x 5mL"",INTRAVENOUS,Resolved,SOLUTION,C01BB,""ANTIARRHYTHMICS, CLASS I AND III"",,2018-06-29,,2018-07-31,""Disruption of the manufacture of the drug."",2018-06-01,2018-08-01,No       "
"24792,02141450,Shortage,""20% PROSOL"",""BAXTER CORPORATION"",""20% PROSOL"",""PHENYLALANINE       "
"49014,02248489,Shortage,""4% ASTRACAINE DENTAL WITH EPINEPHRINE 1:200,000 (0.005MG/ML)"",""DENTSPLY CANADA LIMITED"",""articaine HCl with epinephrine"",""ARTICAINE HYDROCHLORIDE      "
" EPINEPHRINE"",""40MG      "
" 0.005MG"",""100 1.8 mL cartridges/box"",BLOCK/INFILTRATION,Resolved,SOLUTION,N01BB,""ANESTHETICS, LOCAL"",2018-05-10,2018-05-10,2018-07-16,2018-06-15,""Disruption of the manufacture of the drug."",2018-05-10,2018-06-19,No     "
"27274,02248489,Shortage,""4% ASTRACAINE DENTAL WITH EPINEPHRINE 1:200,000 (0.005MG/ML)"",""DENTSPLY CANADA LIMITED"",""Articaine Hydrochloride 40 mg/mL and Epinephrine Injection 1:200,000"",""ARTICAINE HYDROCHLORIDE        "
" EPINEPHRINE"",""40MG      "
```

I download the csv file from this web site :

[web site Drug Shortages canada](https://www.drugshortagescanada.ca/search?perform=0)

Comment: Will you please show a sample of your csv file?

Comment: @richardec Yes of course I put the sample at the bottom of my message

Comment: Your data is a little messed up. Your comma often appears inside column names not between them. Please verify your input file.

Comment: @JonSG Indeed, I downloaded it from its official website : https://www.drugshortagescanada.ca/search?perform=0

Comment: Adding to @JonSG , try converting your csv data to JSON, just to verify it is valid. [csvjson.com](https://csvjson.com/csv2json) can do the job. for you.

Comment: when I use the line of json I have that: ` Expected "\"" or [\n\r] but "\t" found. On line 1 and column 404.`  Now I don't know what the problem is, PS: I download the file as it is, I haven't touched anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I download the example data I end up with a file that looks like:

```
"Discontinuation reports","DISCLAIMER: The information found within this file is presented in the language in which it was written and submitted."
"Report ID","Drug Identification Number","Report Type","Brand name","Company Name","Common or Proper name",Ingredients,Strength(s),"Packaging size","Route of administration","Discontinuation status","Dosage form(s)","ATC Code","ATC description","Discontinuation date","Anticipated discontinuation date",Reason,"Date Created","Date Updated","Tier 3"
156691,02239653,Discontinuation,ANDRODERM,"ALLERGAN INC","Testosterone Transdermal Patch,",TESTOSTERONE,2.5MG,30s,"TRANSDERMAL
TRANSDERMAL",Discontinued,PATCH,G03BA,ANDROGENS,2022-03-10,,"Business reasons",2022-03-14,2022-03-14,No
...
```

Note that the first "row" is meta data and must be discarded:

```py
print(pandas.read_csv("discontinuation_report_export.csv", skiprows=1).head())
```

gives me:

```py
   Report ID  Drug Identification Number      Report Type           Brand name            Company Name  ... Anticipated discontinuation date            Reason Date Created Date Updated Tier 3
0     156691                     2239653  Discontinuation            ANDRODERM            ALLERGAN INC  ...                              NaN  Business reasons   2022-03-14   2022-03-14     No
1     154571                      755885  Discontinuation  APO-PINDOL TAB 10MG              APOTEX INC  ...                              NaN  Business reasons   2022-02-09   2022-02-10     No
2     154574                      755893  Discontinuation  APO-PINDOL TAB 15MG              APOTEX INC  ...                       2022-06-03  Business reasons   2022-02-09   2022-02-09     No
3     154568                      755877  Discontinuation   APO-PINDOL TAB 5MG              APOTEX INC  ...                              NaN  Business reasons   2022-02-09   2022-02-10     No
4     153603                     2448610  Discontinuation             BYDUREON  ASTRAZENECA CANADA INC  ...                       2022-03-31  Business reasons   2022-01-26   2022-01-28     No

[5 rows x 20 columns]
```

Comment: thank you very very  very  very very much its work :)